# Python unpack iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I know `*`operator in Python is used to unpack iterable, such as unpack a list.

However, in practice, we also use `*` operator to unpack iterator, but I haven't found a document explaining it.

See example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

unpack iterable

```
>>> print(*a)
1,2,3
```

unpack iterator

```
>>> it = iter(a)
>>> print(*it)
1,2,3
```

Comment: Despite the wording in the Python documentation, it's not really an operator, as you can't use it in an arbitrary expression. It's special syntax allowed in the argument list to a function call and (in Python 3) on the *left* side of an assignment.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements.

Comment: Because all iterators *are iterables*.

Answer (score 3):

asterisk `*` is iterable unpacking operator

> Iterable is an object, which one can iterate over. It generates an
> Iterator when passed to iter() method. Iterator is an object, which is
> used to iterate over an iterable object using **next**() method.
> Iterators have **next**() method, which returns the next item of the
> object.
>
> Note that every iterator is also an iterable, but not every iterable
> is an iterator.

(from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-iterable-iterator/))

in your example your iterator is an iterable so you can apply `*` the iterable unpacking operator

you can have a look over [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

Answer (score 2):

This works because `iter`, applied to an iterator, returns the same iterator:

> `iterator.__iter__()`
>   Return the iterator object itself. This is
>   required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the
>   for and in statements. This method corresponds to the tp_iter slot of
>   the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.

Using an object in an expression list already results in the creation of an iterator. So `func(*iter(foo))` has the same effect as `func(*foo)`, assuming the iterable/iterator protocols have been correctly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator (starred expression) calls the `__iter__` method.
Demo

```py
class d(dict):
   def __iter__(self):
       for x in dict.__iter__(self):
           print(99)
           yield x

print(*d(a=1, b=2))
# 99
# 99
# a b
```